# Which Azure IoT resources are really needed for basic Remote Monitoring?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-sdk

I'm developing a basic Azure IoT Remote Monitoring solution with the Azure Solution Accelerator "Remote Monitoring". When I start to actually pay for services and stop using a free account, very soon the cash starts to pile up and there seem to be very many resources created behind the scenes. I'm wondering which resources I really need and which one I could throw away to save money. These are the resources that I have:

- App Service plan
- App Service
- Network interface
- Network security group
- Public IP address
- Virtual network
- Storage account
- Azure Cosmos DB account
- Device Provisioning Service
- Event Hubs Namespace
- App Service
- App Service plan
- IoT Hub
- Key vault
- Logic app
- Azure Maps Account
- API Connection
- Disk
- Storage account (2)
- Stream Analytics job
- Time Series Insights environment
- Time Series Insights event source
- Virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB is probably one of the more expensive resources in your list so if you can find a way to swap some other datastore for it you can save some money.

Take a look at [Remote Monitoring architectural choices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-remote-monitoring-architectural-choices).  The Azure IoT Remote Monitoring solution accelerator is an open-source, MIT licensed, solution accelerator. To help you speed up your IoT development process, it shows common IoT scenarios such as:

- Device connectivity
- Device management
- Stream processing
  The Remote Monitoring solution follows the recommended Azure IoT reference architecture.

This article describes the key architectural and technical choices made in each of the Remote Monitoring subsystems. However, the technical choices Microsoft made in the Remote Monitoring solution aren't the only way to implement a remote monitoring IoT solution. You should regard the technical implementation as a baseline for building a successful application and you should modify it to:

- Fit the available skills and experience in your organization.
- Meet your vertical application needs.